# ¿Como puedo compartir un mensaje por Telegram atravez de una url a un username especifico?

Tags: url, telegram

Estoy intentando compartir un mensaje atravez de una url por Telegram a un contacto especifico:

He intentado de las siguientes formas pero ninguna funciona.

tg://msg?text=Texto...&to=+34123456789

t.me/username?text=Texto

Alguna idea de como puedo hacerlo?

Gracias desde ya.

Comment: tal vez lograste tu cometido, estoy intentando lo

Comment: Estoy en lo mismo. Tengo ésto: tg://resolve?domain=NombreDeUsuario     Te abre el chat con el usuario pero falta el modo de rellenar con un mensaje predefinido. Si encuentro algo te informo por aquí.

Answer (score 0):

Yo logre enviar un mensaje gracias a la API de telegram desde un bot que yo cree, pero debe ser algo similar

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot[id_bot]:[token_bot]/sendlocation?chat_id=[chat_id]&latitude=-39.815892&longitude=-73.246818
```

Lo primero que hice fue encontrar el chat id , cada chat tiene un unico ID ... asi evitas colocar el numero de la persona a la que quieres enviarle el mensaje
Después hice que mi bot me enviara la dirección ubicada en esa latitud y longitud.

Podrías tratar de indagar más con la API de Telegram y hacer peticions POST con Postman ,porque sé que se puede enviar mensajes de texto de la misma forma.
Ojala encuentres una buena solución, saludos.

Comment: Yo lo que quiero lograr es que me contacten a mi ya con un mensaje predeterminado atravez de una url por Telegram. Pero al parecer no se puede directamente.